# How to change the output in 1 SQL column to be the same result in every row

Tags: sql-server

Below is my SQL Statement:

```
Select glm_prft_ctr as STORE, glm_account as ACCOUNT, glm_group AS CLASS,
glm_description as DESCRIPTION, 
glm_amt_period0 + glm_amt_period1 + glm_amt_period2 + glm_amt_period3 +
glm_amt_period4 as BALANCE
From gl_master_in
Where glm_prft_ctr = 410
Or glm_prft_ctr = 14101
AND glm_series = 'FY12'
Group by glm_account, glm_description, glm_prft_ctr, glm_group,
glm_amt_period0, glm_amt_period1, glm_amt_period2, glm_amt_period3, glm_amt_period4
```

Below is the Result and what prompted the question:

```
STORE   ACCOUNT CLASS   DESCRIPTION         BALANCE
410     36000   RE      RETAINED EARNINGS   396367.61
14101   36000   RE      RETAINED EARNINGS   -20505.93
```

I need to have the result for STORE to be 7410 is all rows returned.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 7410 as STORE, 
       glm_account as ACCOUNT, 
       glm_group AS CLASS,
       glm_description as DESCRIPTION, 
       glm_amt_period0 + glm_amt_period1 + glm_amt_period2 + glm_amt_period3 + glm_amt_period4 as BALANCE
From gl_master_in
Where glm_prft_ctr = 410 Or glm_prft_ctr = 14101
AND glm_series = 'FY12'
Group by glm_account, glm_description, glm_prft_ctr, glm_group, glm_amt_period0, glm_amt_period1, glm_amt_period2, glm_amt_period3, glm_amt_period4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, like this:

```
Select '7410' as STORE, glm_account as ACCOUNT, glm_group AS CLASS,
glm_description as DESCRIPTION, 
glm_amt_period0 + glm_amt_period1 + glm_amt_period2 + glm_amt_period3 +
glm_amt_period4 as BALANCE
From gl_master_in
Where glm_prft_ctr = 410
Or glm_prft_ctr = 14101
AND glm_series = 'FY12'
Group by glm_account, glm_description, glm_prft_ctr, glm_group,
glm_amt_period0, glm_amt_period1, glm_amt_period2, glm_amt_period3, glm_amt_period4
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have

```
Where glm_prft_ctr = 410 
Or glm_prft_ctr = 14101
```

Which makes STORE = 410 OR 14101. Do you want...

```
Where glm_prft_ctr = 410 
Or glm_prft_ctr = 14101 
Or glm_prft_ctr = 7410
```

Or

```
Where glm_prft_ctr = 7410
```

Or one of the other provided answers that gets STORE info from 410/14101 and names it 7410.